# IntelliJ IDEA - Kotlin: Unresolved reference: eq method

Tags: intellij-idea, kotlin

Am using IntelliJ IDEA 2019.1.2 (Ultimate Edition) with Kotlin (kotlinc-jvm 1.3.31) on macOS Mojave 10.14.5.

When I created a Kotlin JVM project and added a Kotlin file entitled "Nullability.kt" with the following code (extension function with a main() method):

```
fun List<Int>.allNonZero() = all { it > 0 }

fun main() {
    val list1 = listOf(1, 2, 3)
    list1.allNonZero() eq true
}
```

IntelliJ IDEA highlights "eq" in red and it states:

```
Kotlin: Unresolved reference: eq
```

How to resolve this from within IntelliJ IDEA?

Comment: Why do you think this should compile in the first place? Where is this `eq` method supposed to come from? Where did you read that such a method existed?

Comment: Its from a Coursera class on Kotlin that I am taking

Comment: AFAIK, here is no such `eq` function in the standard Kotlin API. So it's probably an extension function from a library. You need to add that library to your classpath and import the extension function.

Comment: Perhaps it's getting confused with Scala, which does have an `eq` operator?  (It's the identity operator, similar to `===` in Kotlin.)

Answer (score 21):

Found it, inside the Coursera course, Kotlin has a Playground where the code is hidden but you can expand it and view it by clicking on the + sign.

```
infix fun <T> T.eq(other: T) {
    if (this == other) println("OK")
    else println("Error: $this != $other")
}
```